# How can pre-define a length of maze path when generating maze

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying create a maze of words with pre-defined length of found path, But have no clue about what algorithm would make it possible.

For ex: I want the length from cells start [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxs0N.png) to end [2] should be 11( the length of "onetwothree").

Here is the current code I am using to generate the maze:

```js
var demotext = "onetwothree";
var widthmaze = (demotext.length + 5) / 2 + 1;
var heightmaze = (demotext.length + 5) / 2 - 1;

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = display(maze(widthmaze, heightmaze));


function maze(x, y) {
  var n = x * y - 1;
  if (n < 0) {
    alert("illegal maze dimensions");
    return;
  }
  var horiz = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < x + 1; j++) horiz[j] = [],
    verti = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < x + 1; j++) verti[j] = [],
    here = [Math.floor(Math.random() * x), Math.floor(Math.random() * y)],
    path = [here],
    unvisited = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < x + 2; j++) {
    unvisited[j] = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < y + 1; k++)
      unvisited[j].push(j > 0 && j < x + 1 && k > 0 && (j != here[0] + 1 || k != here[1] + 1));
  }
  while (0 < n) {
    var potential = [
      [here[0] + 1, here[1]],
      [here[0], here[1] + 1],
      [here[0] - 1, here[1]],
      [here[0], here[1] - 1]
    ];
    var neighbors = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
      if (unvisited[potential[j][0] + 1][potential[j][1] + 1])
        neighbors.push(potential[j]);
    if (neighbors.length) {
      n = n - 1;
      next = neighbors[Math.floor(Math.random() * neighbors.length)];
      unvisited[next[0] + 1][next[1] + 1] = false;
      if (next[0] == here[0])
        horiz[next[0]][(next[1] + here[1] - 1) / 2] = true;
      else
        verti[(next[0] + here[0] - 1) / 2][next[1]] = true;
      path.push(here = next);
    } else
      here = path.pop();
  }
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    horiz: horiz,
    verti: verti
  };
}

function display(m) {

  var text = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < m.x * 2 + 1; j++) {
    var line = [];
    if (0 == j % 2)
      for (var k = 0; k < m.y * 4 + 1; k++)
        if (0 == k % 4)
          line[k] = '+';
        else
    if (j > 0 && m.verti[j / 2 - 1][Math.floor(k / 4)])
      line[k] = ' ';
    else
      line[k] = '-';
    else
      for (var k = 0; k < m.y * 4 + 1; k++)
        if (0 == k % 4)
          if (k > 0 && m.horiz[(j - 1) / 2][k / 4 - 1])
            line[k] = ' ';
          else
            line[k] = '|';
    else
    if (2 == k % 4)
      line[k] = demotext[Math.floor(Math.random() * demotext.length)];
    else
      line[k] = ' ';



    if (0 == j) {line[1] =  line[3] =  ' '; line[2] = '1'};
    if (m.x * 2 - 1 == j) line[4 * m.y] = '2';
    text.push(line.join('') + '\r\n');
  }
  return text.join('');
}
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Moving start and end point to make the path length match with text maybe the solution but I do not know how to implement it. Any help would be great !

Ps: I would like the result can be like this:

[image: Result Image]

Comment: Can you provide what would be an acceptable output?

Comment: @trincot I have updated my question. The result path will be 11 the length of text "onetwothree"

Comment: The algorithm you're using "grows" a maze and the solution path is generated as an emergent behavior. This means that it's going to very hard to end up with a solution of a specific length. Alternatively, there are algorithms that generate the solution path first and then grow the maze from there. That sort of algorithm would be much easier to cause to generate a fixed-length solution.